# What does angular scripts optimization do? Angular 14

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

I updated my project to angular v14 from v9. Until v12 there was no problem but now I can't build it anymore. It failes with an `Error: Optimization error [default-src_app_main_collection_module_ts.js]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ({)`.

If in `angular.json` I disable scripts optimization ( `{ "configurations": { "production": { "optimization": { "scripts": false }}}}` ), the error does not appear. I think it might has something to do with the transcription from ts to js files but I do not know whats causing the problem.

So there are two questions:

1. Do you know something about this error? (There may be an incompatibility of typescript transcription methode I use and the angular 14 optimizer but I could not find it.)
2. What does script optimization do? If the scripts optimization is not important I will just disable it.

Thanks for your help in advance!

```
"dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^14.2.7",
        "@angular/cdk": "14.2.5",
        "@angular/common": "^14.2.7",
        "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.7",
        "@angular/core": "^14.2.7",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^14.0.0-beta.41",
        "@angular/forms": "^14.2.7",
        "@angular/material": "^14.2.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.7",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.7",
        "@angular/router": "14.2.7",
        "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.1",
        "@editorjs/editorjs": "^2.25.0",
        "@editorjs/paragraph": "^2.8.0",
        "@flowjs/flow.js": "2.14.1",
        "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^14.0.0",
        "@stomp/stompjs": "^6.1.0",
        "@types/jquery": "3.5.14",
        "@types/resize-observer-browser": "^0.1.7",
        "@types/sockjs-client": "^1.5.0",
        "angular-resizable-element": "^3.4.0",
        "angular-resize-event": "^2.1.0",
        "angular-shepherd": "^14.0.0",
        "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "^9.0.0",
        "angular2-virtual-scroll": "0.4.16",
        "copy-image-clipboard": "^2.1.2",
        "core-js": "^3.26.0",
        "dompurify": "^2.1.1",
        "event-source-polyfill": "^1.0.21",
        "fs-extra": "^10.1.0",
        "git-describe": "^4.0.4",
        "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "jquery.scrollto": "2.1.3",
        "jstree": "^3.3.10",
        "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
        "material-icons": "^1.10.8",
        "moment": "^2.29.3",
        "ng-recaptcha": "^10.0.0",
        "ngx-clipboard": "14.0.1",
        "ngx-contextmenu": "^6.0.0",
        "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^14.0.0",
        "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.0.1",
        "ngx-scrollbar": "^10.0.1",
        "overlayscrollbars": "1.13.0",
        "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
        "shepherd.js": "^10.0.1",
        "sockjs-client": "^1.5.1",
        "tslib": "^2.4.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.6",
        "@angular/cli": "14.2.6",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.7",
        "@angular/language-service": "^14.2.7",
        "@types/jasmine": "^4.3.0",
        "@types/node": "^16.11.7",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "husky": "^4.3.8",
        "jasmine-core": "^4.4.0",
        "jasmine-reporters": "^2.5.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
        "karma": "~6.4.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "^5.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
        "karma-junit-reporter": "2.0.1",
        "lint-staged": "^13.0.3",
        "ng-mocks": "^14.3.1",
        "ng-packagr": "^14.2.2",
        "prettier": "^1.19.1",
        "protractor": "~7.0.0",
        "puppeteer": "^19.2.0",
        "sonar-scanner": "^3.1.0",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0",
        "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
        "typescript": "^4.8.4"
    },
```

Comment: Did you follow the upgrade guidelines from Angular update page? It can be accessed via this link https://update.angular.io

Comment: As much as I could. I did not understand what each point is and I have some old dependencies, which I cannot update but still need.
Still the webapp works fine it's just this optimization of scripts thats bugging me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used esNext as target in tsconfig.json. This did not work together with the outdated tslint installation. The solution was to use **es2020 as target in tsconfig** and refactor tslint with **eslint**.

Answer (score 1):

so if you look at their source code, looks like only thing optimization do is just run the compile code against esbuild.transform to minify, and run the result agaisnt tersor to optimize bundle size. so it's likely you have syntax in the file that either of this plugin didn't like. maybe you could run it against --verbose mode to get more insight.

here's their `javascript-optimizer-worker.ts` for you to look at.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/main/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/webpack/plugins/javascript-optimizer-worker.ts

Comment: Thank you for the comment it pushed me in the right direction.